# Which is the fastest way to search a value within a set of many "range" objects in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, search, optimization

I have a list of many Python objects like this:

```
class RangeClass(object):

    def __init__(self,address,size):
        self.address=address
        self.size=size
        #other attributes and methods...
```

Then, I have a list (rangelist) of RangeClass objects.

I need to find within which range a given value is.

I can use some code like this:

```
for r in ragelist:
    if(value>=r.address and value<(r.address+r.size)):
        return r
return None
```

But I think there is a faster way. Ranges have arbitrary size, but we can assume that they don't overlap.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have many values to test, then you could use the [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) to find which range the values are in more quickly.

If

- `m` = the number of values to test, and
- `n` = `len(rangelist)`

then looping through the values and rangelist as you suggest would take `O(m*n)` time.

If you use bisection, then you must first sort the starting addresses `O(nlogn)` and find each value's place in rangelist `O(m*logn)`.
So if

```
O(nlogn + m*logn) < O(m*n)
```

then bisection wins. For large `n`, `O(m*logn)` is miniscule compared to `O(m*n)`.
So the inequality above would be true if

```
O(nlogn) < O(m*n)
```

or equivalently, when

```
C log(n) < m
```

for some constant C.

---

Thus, when `n` is large and `C log(n) < m`, you might try something like

```
import bisect

class RangeClass(object):

    def __init__(self,address,size):
        self.address=address
        self.size=size
    def __str__(self):
        return '[{0},{1})'.format(self.address,self.address+self.size)
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.address<other.address

rangelist=sorted([RangeClass(i,1) for i in (1,3,4,5,7.5)])
starts=[r.address for r in rangelist]

def find_range(value):
    start_idx=bisect.bisect(starts,value)-1
    try:
        r=rangelist[start_idx]
    except IndexError:
        return None
    start=r.address
    end=r.address+r.size
    if start<=value<end:
        return rangelist[start_idx]
    return None    

print(','.join(str(r) for r in rangelist))

for value in (0,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10):
    r=find_range(value)
    if r:
        print('{v} in {r}'.format(v=value,r=str(r)))
    else:
        print('{v} not in any range'.format(v=value))
```

Comment: You are right about bisection, but the math you put in there is naive at best. `O(nlogn) < O(m*n)` is not equivalent to `log(n) < m`. You cannot compute the number of elements where one case would be better than the other from the landau notation. All it says that such a number exists. `O( .. )` is a set of functions after all!

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: Please help me improve my post. I'd already changed "equivalent" to "ignoring constant factors" before your comment. I know that can be made more precise, but didn't think that would improve the understandability of my post. Do you think there are still errors in what I'm saying?

Comment: You're trying to decide at what problem size one algorithm becomes faster than the other. To do that with the `O( .. )` you'd have to know how much time each operation in the algorithm takes. These factors vary too much between hardware, so the landau notation was invented so that arguing about runtime is possible without having to think about the time different operations take. You can't use it to calculate a number however, as all the constants are simply left unspecified. The only way find out at which problem size one algorithm becomes faster than the other is benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. All you can do is take advantage of Python's relational operator chaining.

```
if r.address <= value < (r.address + r.size):
```

You could also define `__contains__` on `RangeClass` to allow you to use `in` to find it instead.

```
class RangeClass(object):
   ...
  def __contains__(self, val):
    return self.address <= val < (self.address + self.size)

 ...
  if value in r:
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the comparison operator in Range, have the range list sorted, and use bisect to search for the range a value belongs in:

```
import bisect
def find_range(value):
    index = bisect.bisect(rangelist, value)
    if index not in (0, len(rangelist)):
        index -= 1
    return rangelist[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone,

I am actually using the method proposed by unutbu.

Moreover, I add another optimization:

```
if(value <= first_range_value or value >= last_range_value):
    return None
```

Where first_range_value and last_range_value have been computed before, and they are the smallest  r.address  value and the largest  r.address+r.size value .

This is worthing in my application, but it really depends on the distribution of ranges and values.